# Write functions that run in O(1) time

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees, binary-trees

This Question can be found in the book: [ODS: An Introduction](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ZZCJvrDe5bIC&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (Chapter 6)

> Suppose we are given a binary tree with pre-, post-, and in-order numbers assigned to the nodes. Show how these numbers can be used to answer each of the following questions in constant time:
>
> a. Given a node n, determine the size of the subtree rooted at n.
>
> b. Given a node n, determine the depth of n.
>
> c. Given two nodes n and m, determine if n is an ancestor of m.

I am able to solve the question after building the binary tree using the given post-order and in-order numbers. But is it possible to write procedures that run in O(1) time?

Comment: The first one should be straightforward, do you understand the definitions of the different traversals? Where are you stuck? Look at the pre-order and post-order values of n ... What do they tell you?

Comment: The third one is also straightforward. You just have to check that $n$ was first visited not after $m$ and last visited not before $m$. In other words you are checking that $m$ lies in the subtree rooted at $n$.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  This contains three questions in one.